# Weird vertical lines when include a tex file for table content

Tags: latex

Here is my minimal code to create a 2x2 table

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Cell 1 & Cell 2 \\ \hline
    \input{vt_list.tex}       
  \end{tabular}    
\end{table}    
\end{document}
```

The included `vs_list.tex` file has only one line

```
Cell 3 & Cell 4 \\ \hline
```

However, such code created a weird table as below.  However, if I don't use `\input` and write the `Cell 3 & Cell 4 \\ \hline` directly in the main tex file, then there is no such weird vertical lines at the 3rd row.

[image: Fig. weired table]

I am running latex under vscode. In the beginning of the execution, it prints out the following, which provides some version info.

```
Rc files read:
  /etc/LatexMk
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 20 November 2021, version: 4.76.
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      '/home/pohetsn/git/arrhythmia_detection/report/incarda/test.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567988/36296

Comment: Thanks for the link! The table now looks like before with `\AddToHook{env/tabular/begin}{\let\input\@@input}` and `\AddToHook{env/longtable/begin}{\let\input\@@input}`